# How to run multiple select query at once in sequelize using single await

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Have to run both codes at a single time. Don't want to wait and then fire next query but wait for both query execution complete.

```
products = await Product.findAll()
.then(data => {
  return data;
})
.catch(error => {
  //
});

variationProducts = await VariationProduct.findAll()
.then(data => {
  return data;
})
.catch(error => {
  //
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may choose

```
const [ productsPromise, variationProductsPromise ] = await Promise.all([Product.findAll(), VariationProduct.findAll()]);
```

> OR

```
const [ productsPromise, variationProductsPromise ] = await { Product.findAll(), VariationProduct.findAll()}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
try {
    const [products, variationProducts] = await Promise.all([
        Product.findAll(),
        VariationProduct.findAll()
    ]);

    // Do what you need with the result;
}
catch(e) {
    console.error('Problem in getting data', e);
    throw e; // Or do what you want.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
Promise.all([Product.findAll(), VariationProduct.findAll()]).then(data => {
    // data [0] is products
    // data [1] is variationProducts 
}).catch(error => {
    // oops some error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const products = Product.findAll();
const variationProducts = VariationProduct.findAll();

const productsPromise = await products;
const variationProductsPromise = await variationProducts;
```